# How to make every second post reversed from first with nth-child

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I saw on http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/ that even posts have image to the right, and odd posts image to the left. This is without a doubt solved with css.

I tried to solve this with css, but without success.

This is the code i have:

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
   <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" image>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" text>
    </div>
  </div>
    
      
</div>
```

i Want to make something like webdesignerdepot.com
Like this image i made:
[image]

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Looking at their source code and I think this is actually taken care of with HTML :-/ This is cool though and probably could be done in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can utilize CSS' `float` attributes, along with `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` selectors.

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/xyz1f7jx/) where I've used the following CSS:

```
.post:nth-child(odd) .row div:nth-child(odd),
.post:nth-child(even) .row div:nth-child(even) {
  float: left;
  height: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

.post:nth-child(odd) .row div:nth-child(even),
.post:nth-child(even) .row div:nth-child(odd) {
  float: right;
  height: 260px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Added  the same into my media query with width of 100% alnd it looks and works great :)

Comment: @Elisimo Awesome. :) You're most welcome and happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

Without `float` but `display`, `direction` will do the job for you.

```
display:flex;
```

```css
.row .row {
  display:flex;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:red solid;
  }
.row div  .row >div {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100%;
  background:turquoise;
  border:solid red;
  direction:ltr;
  }
.row .row div:nth-child(even) {
  background:tomato;
  }
.row :nth-child(even) .row{
  direction:rtl;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or `display:table`

```css
.row .row {
  display:table;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:red solid;
  }
.row div  .row >div {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  background:turquoise;
  border:solid red;
  direction:ltr;
  }
.row .row div:nth-child(even) {
  background:tomato;
  }
.row :nth-child(even) .row{
  direction:rtl;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
      
  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6"> text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
      
    
</div>
```

or `display:flex` and `order`

```css
.row .row {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: red solid;
}
.row div .row >div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: turquoise;
  border: solid red;
}
.row .row div:nth-child(even) {
  background: tomato;
}
.row :nth-child(even) .row div:nth-child(even) {
  order: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col=xs-12 post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">image</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">text</div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Very good. But display:flex doesn't respect bootstrap classes.
Visually on larger devices it looks very good,

Comment: With some added meadi query..It looks excelent. Thank you my brother :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using Bootstrap. Maybe it would be worth you using their built-in `.col-md-push-*` and `.col-md-pull-*` modifier classes to swap them around.

From the Bootstrap docs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

What this will result in is the two columns being reversed in order (`.col-md-9` will render as coming after `.col-md-3`).

Comment: Hi there. But the point is. Blogs pull data from a database.
I want to pull data from database
Lets say i have 10 posts before you can go to  second page.
If i use PULL or PUSH classes i would have to repeat my php loop 10 times. I want o pull data once, and let css do the rest. I think its possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with @krypsin's answer as you seem to be using bootstrap. But if you weren't, you could use css to do something like:

```
.post:nth-of-type(even) .row .col-xs-12.col-md-6:first-of-type{
  float: right;
}
.post:nth-of-type(even) .row .col-xs-12.col-md-6:last-of-type{
  float: left;
}
```

The `:nth-of-type(even)` applies styles to the children of every second .post class. The `:last-of-type` selector picks the last instance of that element type, and the `:first-of-type` selector applies styles to the first instance.